# Websphere hacia .NET SSLHandshakeException

Tags: .net, websphere

Hola en un servidor (Linux) se actualizo recientemente a la version 10.0.0.9 del IBM Integration BUS (IIB), creemos, no estamos totalmente seguros, que luego de eso cuando intentamos consumir por https un servicio de .NET, otro servidor Windows, nos devuelve la siguiente excepción:

> SOAP(http://tempuri.org/Consulta):ESB-3165 - (): An error occurred
>   whilst performing an SSL socket operation --
>   ([5]connect,[5]javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed
>   connection during handshake)

Hemos desintalado e instalado en el servidor del IIB el certificado varias veces y nada, hemos visto que no este denegada en el Internet Information Server(IIS) la IP del servidor del IIB, la cuestión es que aparese ese error una y otra vez.
Un dato mas es que desde mi ordenador (y hemos probado en otras 3 estaciones de trabajo en Windows), me instale el certificado y el servicio se comunica perfectamente con el servicio de .NET, es decir, al parecer el problema es solo desde el servidor del IIB al servidor de .NET
Otro dato es que antes funcionaba perfectamente.
Desde el servidor de IIB hay comunicación al servidor de .NET (hay Telnet)
El certificado es válido todavía, de hecho en mi ordenador funciona.
Por favor alguien podrá darme alguna guia de que pudiera ser el problema o por donde seguir revisando. 
Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Bienvenido, para que tus preguntas sean mejores recibidas por la comunidad te invito a leer [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.

Dentro de las propiedades del nodo **SOAP Request**, hay una pestaña que se llama Transporte HTTP. Dentro de la misma, hay una opcion que se llama **Protocolo (si se utiliza SSL)**; la opción por defecto es **TLS**. Recomiendo verificar cual de las opciones se ajusta al escenario al que se enfrentan.

Espero que esto pueda ayudar.

Saludos.